# How to make a close() using stack in GUI by passing the path of the open file

Tags: java, user-interface, stack, file-handling

Query : in a notepad made using file handling , I have to close the last opened notepad using stacks such that ; the first path that was opened will remain in the last . i am new to stacks i understand the functions "push" and "pop" but i am having trouble passing the path to them .

```
String paths;

public void open(){

JFileChooser open=new JFileChooser();

int option=open.showOpenDialog(this);
push(paths);

if(option==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
this.textarea.setText(" ");

try{
Scanner scan=new Scanner(open.getSelectedFile().getPath());
paths=open.getSelectedFile().getPath();
while(scan.hasNext()){
textarea.append(scan.nextLine());
System.out.println("\n");

}
}

catch (Exception ex){

System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

}
}
}

public void close(){

s.push(paths);
s.pop();
```

I want the close() to close the last opened path first

Comment: Try using javafx

Comment: its an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my solution . Im posting here for newbies like me .. its not that difficult

```
//first youll need the path(globally declared) you want to put in Stack so Im using paths form open()//
close()
{ stack<String> s=new <String> stack();
  if(s.isempty())
  { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Stack is Empty");}
  else
  s.pop();
  s.peek(path);
   //insert reading file code here//
}
```